# Covariance in a subclass

Tags: scala

```
sealed trait Option[+A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
case class Some[A](get: A) extends Option[A]

class C1() {}
class C2() extends C1 {}
val x1: Some[C1] = Some(new C2)           //> x1  : T.Some[T.C1] = Some(T$C2@4b5695c8)
val x2: Some[C2] = Some(new C2)           //> x2  : T.Some[T.C2] = Some(T$C2@664bb5d8)
// val x3: Some[C1] = x2 // Type mismatch
```

What is the purpose of `+A` in `Some[+A]`? If I define it as `Some[A]` it will be covariant too, I understand it inherits covariance from `Option[A]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not, consider this case:

```
sealed trait Maybe[+A]
case object Empty extends Maybe[Nothing]
case class Just[A](x: A) extends Maybe[A]

scala> val j: Maybe[AnyRef] = Just[String]("Hello")
j: Maybe[AnyRef] = Just(Hello)
```

and this:

```
scala> val j: Just[AnyRef] = Just[String]("Hello")
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Just[String]
 required: Just[AnyRef]
Note: String <: AnyRef, but class Just is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
       val j: Just[AnyRef] = Just[String]("Hello")
```

I understand that declaring a type of variable as `Some` is foolish, but i've seen such code.

Comment: Edited my question, something strange is going on. Does it break substitution principle or am I missing something simple?

Comment: @VictorMoroz: in your update, the type annotation on `x1` drives the type inference of the RHS, so `new C2` is inferred to be of type `C1`. Put a `C2` type parameter on `Some` and you'll get an error.